# Azure KeyVaultClient Hyak.Common exception whilte trying to get access token

Tags: c#, .net, azure

I have a problem when trying to create a KeyVaultClient. I use the sample code

```
    async Task<string> GetAccessToken(string authority, string resource, string scope)
    {
        var clientId = "ID";
        var clientSecret = "SECRET";
        ClientCredential clientCredential = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);

        var context = new AuthenticationContext(authority, TokenCache.DefaultShared);
        var result = await context.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, clientCredential);

        return result.AccessToken;
    }

    public async void Test()
    {
        var vaultAddress = "url";
        KeyVaultClient keyVaultClient = new KeyVaultClient(new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(GetAccessToken));
    }
```

when I try to create a keyVaultClient I receive an exception

> An exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in
>   Hyak.Common.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The type initializer for
>   'Hyak.Common.ServiceClient`1' threw an exception.

When i go to exception details I can see

> {"Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Threading.Tasks,
>   Version=1.0.12.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file
>   specified.":"Microsoft.Threading.Tasks, Version=1.0.12.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"}
>
> My packages.config:

```
 <package id="Hyak.Common" version="1.1.0" targetFramework="net46" />  
 <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Common" version="2.0.4"      targetFramework="net46" />
 <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Common.Dependencies" version="1.0.0"      targetFramework="net46" />
 <package id="Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net46" />
 <package id="Microsoft.Azure.SqlDatabase.ElasticScale.Client" version="1.3.2" targetFramework="net46" />
 <package id="Microsoft.Bcl" version="1.1.10" targetFramework="net46" />
 <package id="Microsoft.Bcl.Async" version="1.0.168" targetFramework="net46" />   
 <package id="Microsoft.Bcl.Build" version="1.0.21" targetFramework="net46" />
 <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory" version="3.13.7" targetFramework="net46" />
 <package id="Microsoft.Net.Http" version="2.2.29" targetFramework="net46" userInstalled="true" />
 <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="9.0.1" targetFramework="net46"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are missing `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` Maybe you can show your package.config to see which package you have installed.
If you are missing `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` then just install it with Package Manager Console: 
`Install-Package Microsoft.Bcl.Async`

Comment: Unfortunately that's not it. I have Microsoft.Bcl.Async.

Comment: Please make sure whether you could see a reference to Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.dll under References node in Solution Explorer. And please check whether Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.dll file are existing in Microsoft.Bcl.Async.1.0.168\lib folder in your project packages. Besides, please try to uninstall packages from your project and reinstall Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault and Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory packages.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I'm missing the reference to `Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.dll` and `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` nuget package contains it.